# How to parse date/time from string?

Tags: c++, datetime, boost, utc, boost-date-time

**Input**: strings with date and optional time. Different representations would be nice but necessary. The strings are user-supplied and can be malformed. Examples:

- `"2004-03-21 12:45:33"` (I consider this the default layout)
- `"2004/03/21 12:45:33"` (optional layout)
- `"23.09.2004 04:12:21"` (german format, optional)
- `"2003-02-11"` (time may be missing)

**Needed Output**: Seconds since Epoch (1970/01/01 00:00:00) or some other fixed point.

**Bonus**: Also, reading the UTC-offset of the local system time would be great.

The input is assumed to be a local time on the machine in question.
The output needs to be UTC. System is Linux only (Debian Lenny and Ubuntu needed).

I have tried to use `boost/date_time`, but must admit I can't wrap my head around the documentation. The following works without the needed conversion from system local time to UTC:

```
std::string date = "2000-01-01";
boost::posix_time::ptime ptimedate = boost::posix_time::time_from_string(date);
ptimedate += boost::posix_time::hours(Hardcoded_UTC_Offset);// where to get from?
struct tm = boost::posix_time::to_tm(ptimedate);
int64_t ticks = mktime(&mTmTime);
```

I think `boost::date_time` can provide the needed UTC offset, but I wouldn't know how.

Comment: I believe you'll have to parse them on your own (perhaps with spirit) because the single-digit month number in "2004-3-21" isn't parsable by any of the boost time IO format specifiers http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html#date_time.format_flags

Comment: @Cubbi: if that's the only issue, it's much much easier to check for that and insert a 0 in the string than to bring spirit into the picture.

Comment: @Cubbi - you can handle custom input and output formats in `boost::date_time` - `boost::spirit` is overkill here

Comment: @Cubbi: If single digit is a problem, the user would be required to enter only double digit values. I will edit my post since this is not the real issue here.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Although I don't know how to format a single-digit month input in boost, I can do it after the two-digit edit:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>
namespace bt = boost::posix_time;
const std::locale formats[] = {
std::locale(std::locale::classic(),new bt::time_input_facet("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")),
std::locale(std::locale::classic(),new bt::time_input_facet("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")),
std::locale(std::locale::classic(),new bt::time_input_facet("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")),
std::locale(std::locale::classic(),new bt::time_input_facet("%Y-%m-%d"))};
const size_t formats_n = sizeof(formats)/sizeof(formats[0]);

std::time_t pt_to_time_t(const bt::ptime& pt)
{
    bt::ptime timet_start(boost::gregorian::date(1970,1,1));
    bt::time_duration diff = pt - timet_start;
    return diff.ticks()/bt::time_duration::rep_type::ticks_per_second;

}
void seconds_from_epoch(const std::string& s)
{
    bt::ptime pt;
    for(size_t i=0; i<formats_n; ++i)
    {
        std::istringstream is(s);
        is.imbue(formats[i]);
        is >> pt;
        if(pt != bt::ptime()) break;
    }
    std::cout << " ptime is " << pt << '\n';
    std::cout << " seconds from epoch are " << pt_to_time_t(pt) << '\n';
}
int main()
{
    seconds_from_epoch("2004-03-21 12:45:33");
    seconds_from_epoch("2004/03/21 12:45:33");
    seconds_from_epoch("23.09.2004 04:12:21");
    seconds_from_epoch("2003-02-11");
}
```

note that the seconds-from-epoch output will be assuming the date was in UTC:

```
~ $ ./test | head -2
ptime is 2004-Mar-21 12:45:33
seconds from epoch are 1079873133
~ $ date -d @1079873133
Sun Mar 21 07:45:33 EST 2004
```

You could probably use `boost::posix_time::c_time::localtime()` from `#include <boost/date_time/c_time.hpp>` to get this conversion done assuming the input is in the current time zone, but it is rather inconsistent: for me, for example, the result will be different between today and next month, when daylight saving ends.

Comment: Showing how to work with facets is much appreciated. Using localtime is not an option if I understand it right since it would give me the DST-offset of today rather than of the given date.

Comment: @Gabriel Schreiber: You could probably do the DST-offset on the given date, by doing the opposite to what `utc_to_local()` does in `/usr/include/boost/date_time/c_local_time_adjustor.hpp`, which would still use the current computer's zone. A better way is probably something closer to http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/date_time/examples.html#date_time.examples.seconds_since_epoch

Answer (score 12):

[`boost::gregorian`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/date_time/examples.html#date_time.examples.dates_as_strings) has some of the stuff you need without you doing any more work:

```
using namespace boost::gregorian;
{
  // The following date is in ISO 8601 extended format (CCYY-MM-DD)
  std::string s("2000-01-01");
  date d(from_simple_string(s));
  std::cout << to_simple_string(d) << std::endl;
}
```

There is an example on how to use UTC offsets with `boost::posix_time` [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/date_time/examples.html#date_time.examples.simple_time_zone).

You can provide generation of date and time from custom input string formats using [`date_input_facet`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html#date_input_facet_intro) and [`time_input_facet`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html#time_input_facet_intro).  There is an I/O tutorial on [this page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html#io_objects.format_date_parser) that should help you get going.

Comment: Thx for the facet/tutorial linx. Using boost::gregorian does not solve the problem because it doesn't provide time parsing/representation.

Comment: @Gabriel - right, you would have to build your own parser and formatter using these tools to handle all your required cases.  Unless you have unbounded possible input formats, that should be possible using a parser for each format, and a wrapper that identifies the format type and feeds to the appropriate parser.

Comment: @Gabriel - note that when I say parser, this is really nothing complex given your input `string` options.  Just detect each and build the appropriate Boost constructs to parse appropriately into a date_time.

Answer (score 8):

If c-style is acceptable: [strptime](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strptime.html)() is the way to go, because you can specify the format and it can take locale in account:

```
tm brokenTime;
strptime(str.c_str(), "%Y-%m-%d %T", &brokenTime);
time_t sinceEpoch = timegm(brokenTime);
```

Different layouts will have to be checked with the return value (if possible).
Timezone will have to be added to by checking the system clock (localtime_r() with time(), tm_zone)

Comment: strptime has been tried. It is not acceptable because it will happily crash if the string is not well-formed.

Comment: I use it, it doesn't crash here, but experience may differ. I will have to investigate (to google) to be sure...

Comment: @Gabriel: Except for MacOs X Leopard, where strptime seems to be broken, nothing special was found (getdate crashes, Qalculate removed strptime (2004)).  Could you give some information about the system on which it crashes?

Comment: `strptime` is also Linux-specific, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Er, make that POSIX-specific.

Comment: @KyleStrand no worries, by the way, the question mentioned "Linux only".

Answer (score 3):

the simplest, portable solution is to use `scanf`:

```
int year, month, day, hour, minute, second = 0;
int r = 0;

r = scanf ("%d-%d-%d %d:%d:%d", &year, &month, &day,
           &hour, &minute, &second);
if (r == 6) 
{
  printf ("%d-%d-%d %d:%d:%d\n", year, month, day, hour, minute,
          second);
}
else 
{
    r = scanf ("%d/%d/%d %d:%d:%d", &year, &month, &day,
           &hour, &minute, &second);
    // and so on ...
```

Initialize a `struct tm` with the `int` values and pass it to `mktime` to get a calendar time as `time_t`. For timezone conversions, please [see information](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/gmtime/) on `gmtime`.

Comment: C runtime `scanf/printf` introduce buffer management and type safety problems that can be avoided by use of appropriate C++ libraries.

Comment: This doesn't solve the local to utc problem. Also, the string is user-supplied and can be invalid/malformed. I think this can be a problem with scanf?

Comment: @Gabriel if the string is malformed, scanf will not return 6. about utc, i have added some more information to the answer.

Comment: @Steve could you please point out buffer management/type safety problems that can arise in this particular situation and their c++ alternatives? that will be informative.

Comment: (x)printf family all behave unpredictably if format string mismatches inputs in count or type. Why would anybody use printf/scanf in C++? If the q was tagged C this is no issue.

Comment: scanf is fine.  C++ snobbery runs unchecked