# C++ Converting a time string to seconds from the epoch

Tags: c++, c, time, platform-independent

I have a string with the following format:

> 2010-11-04T23:23:01Z

The Z indicates that the time is UTC.
I would rather store this as a epoch time to make comparison easy.

What is the recomended method for doing this?

Currently (after a quck search) the simplist algorithm is:

```
1: <Convert string to struct_tm: by manually parsing string>
2: Use mktime() to convert struct_tm to epoch time.

// Problem here is that mktime uses local time not UTC time.
```

Comment: _mkgmtime() in my CRT.  Ymmv.

Comment: @Loki, we do not need a meta tag to catch all things that are OS-neutral.  Please stop recreating the tag.

Comment: @Charles: Please stop changing my question. I would have though you would have got the hint that I think the edit is invalid after the second time I changed it back.

Comment: @Loki, and I thought you would have gotten the hint that other users on the site do not see the need for a new generic catch-all tag for this question and this question only.  Please either add a tag wiki and add the tag to other questions to which it is relevant, or you're going to continue to see other users remove the tag.

Comment: @Loki - it doesn't help much that the tag has been misspelled all along...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using C++11 functionality we can now use streams to parse times:

The iomanip [`std::get_time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/time_get) will convert a string based on a set of format parameters and convert them into a `struct tz` object.

You can then use `std::mktime()` to convert this into an epoch value.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <locale>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    std::tm t = {};
    std::istringstream ss("2010-11-04T23:23:01Z");

    if (ss >> std::get_time(&t, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"))
    {
        std::cout << std::put_time(&t, "%c") << "\n"
                  << std::mktime(&t) << "\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code does not address OPs issue (I do not know why he accepted it). `std::mktime` assumes local timezone and outputs the wrong time. It gives `1288909381` on my machine (`GMT+01:00` at that date), which is `10 pm`, not `11 pm` at UTC. The correct timestamp however would have been `1288912981`.

Comment: @Zabuza Would you not think the OP knows what he wants better than you? If you don't know why he accepted it then maybe you should clarify that first otherwise your assertion `This code does not address OPs issue` is suspect.

Comment: There's a `timegm()` utility (available on most Linux systems) that will convert from a struct tm to UTC elapsed seconds from epoch = 1970-01-01:00:00:00. In an ISO 8601 time specification -- e.g. 2024-03-05T12:21:00-05:00 -- the hours and seconds represented by the 6 trailing time zone characters are subtracted from the preceding time to give the UTC time. See also: [SQLite: 2. Time Values](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

Answer (score 6):

This is ISO8601 format. You can use `strptime` function to parse it with `%FT%T%z` argument. It is not a part of the C++ Standard though you can use open source implementation of it ([this](http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/lib/libc/time/strptime.c?rev=HEAD), for instance).

Answer (score 5):

You can use a function such as [strptime](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strptime.html) to convert a string to a `struct tm`, instead of parsing it manually.

Answer (score 3):

It's not an exact dup but you will find @Cubbi's answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786201/parsing-of-date-time-from-string-boost/3787188#3787188) useful, I wager.  This specifically assumes UTC input.

Boost also support direct conversion from ISO 8601 via `boost::posix_time::from_iso_string` which calls `boost::date_time::parse_iso_time`, here again you would just strip the trailing 'Z' and treat the TZ as implicit UTC.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>

namespace bt = boost::posix_time;

const std::locale formats[] = {
std::locale(std::locale::classic(),new bt::time_input_facet("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")),
std::locale(std::locale::classic(),new bt::time_input_facet("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")),
std::locale(std::locale::classic(),new bt::time_input_facet("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")),
std::locale(std::locale::classic(),new bt::time_input_facet("%Y-%m-%d"))};
const size_t formats_n = sizeof(formats)/sizeof(formats[0]);

std::time_t pt_to_time_t(const bt::ptime& pt)
{
    bt::ptime timet_start(boost::gregorian::date(1970,1,1));
    bt::time_duration diff = pt - timet_start;
    return diff.ticks()/bt::time_duration::rep_type::ticks_per_second;

}
void seconds_from_epoch(const std::string& s)
{
    bt::ptime pt;
    for(size_t i=0; i<formats_n; ++i)
    {
        std::istringstream is(s);
        is.imbue(formats[i]);
        is >> pt;
        if(pt != bt::ptime()) break;
    }
    std::cout << " ptime is " << pt << '\n';
    std::cout << " seconds from epoch are " << pt_to_time_t(pt) << '\n';
}
int main()
{
    seconds_from_epoch("2004-03-21 12:45:33");
    seconds_from_epoch("2004/03/21 12:45:33");
    seconds_from_epoch("23.09.2004 04:12:21");
    seconds_from_epoch("2003-02-11");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Problem here is that mktime uses local time not UTC time.

Linux provides `timegm` which is what you want (i.e. mktime for UTC time).

Here is my solution, which I forced to only accept "Zulu" (Z timezone). Note
that `strptime` doesn't actually seem to parse the time zone correctly, even 
though glib seems to have some support for that. That is why I just throw an
exception if the string doesn't end in 'Z'.

```
static double EpochTime(const std::string& iso8601Time)
{
    struct tm t;
    if (iso8601Time.back() != 'Z') throw PBException("Non Zulu 8601 timezone not supported");
    char* ptr = strptime(iso8601Time.c_str(), "%FT%T", &t);
    if( ptr == nullptr)
    {
        throw PBException("strptime failed, can't parse " + iso8601Time);
    }
    double t2 = timegm(&t); // UTC
    if (*ptr)
    {
        double fraction = atof(ptr);
        t2 += fraction;
    }
    return t2;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

New answer to an old question.  Rationale for new answer:  In case you want to use `<chrono>` types to solve a problem like this.

In addition to C++11/C++14, you'll need this [free, open source date/time library](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html):

```
#include "tz.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int
main()
{
    std::istringstream is("2010-11-04T23:23:01Z");
    is.exceptions(std::ios::failbit);
    date::sys_seconds tp;
    date::parse(is, "%FT%TZ", tp);
    std::cout << "seconds from epoch is " << tp.time_since_epoch().count() << "s\n";
}
```

This program outputs:

```
seconds from epoch is 1288912981s
```

If the parse fails in any way, an exception will be thrown.  If you would rather not throw exceptions, don't `is.exceptions(std::ios::failbit);`, but instead check for `is.fail()`.

Answer (score 1):

You could utilize the [`boost::date_time`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/date_time.html) and write a small manual parser *(probably regexp-based)* for your strings.

Answer (score 1):

> Problem here is that mktime uses local time not UTC time.

How about just computing the time difference between UTC and local time, then adding it to the value returned by `mktime`?

```
time_t local = time(NULL),
       utc   = mktime(gmtime(&local));
int    diff  = utc - local;
```

Comment: That only gives you the offset for _today_, not for the specific date in question. (Offsets can change, and there is also DST).

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with `strptime()` ?

And on Linux, you even get the 'seconds east of UTC' field relieving you from any need to parse:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {

    const char *timestr = "2010-11-04T23:23:01Z";

    struct tm t;
    strptime(timestr, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ", &t);

    char buf[128];
    strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S", &t);

    std::cout << timestr << " -> " << buf << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Seconds east of UTC " << t.tm_gmtoff << std::endl;
}
```

which for me yields

```
/tmp$ g++ -o my my.cpp 
/tmp$ ./my
2010-11-04T23:23:01Z -> 04 Nov 2010 23:23:01
Seconds east of UTC 140085769590024
```

Comment: That "Seconds east of UTC" value is clearly bogus, since the value shown is in excess of 4 million years.  Timezones should be within a range of +/- 50000 seconds of UTC.

Comment: Darn. You're right. And even when I define _BSD_SOURCE (which the `mktime / ctime` manual page had mentions) it still comes out as too large. I'm missing something else.

Answer (score 1):

X/Open provides a global `timezone` variable which indicates the number of seconds that local time is behind UTC.  You can use this to adjust the output of `mktime()`:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

/* 2010-11-04T23:23:01Z */
time_t zulu_time(const char *time_str)
{
    struct tm tm = { 0 };

    if (!strptime(time_str, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ", &tm))
        return (time_t)-1;

    return mktime(&tm) - timezone;
}
```