# How to effectively assign numerical string values to integers?

Tags: c++

I have a string containing a value of time in HH:MM:SS(':' are a part of the string.) format.I have to convert the time into seconds and give that value to an integer variable.I am not aware of any function that can help me do it.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137748/c-converting-a-time-string-to-seconds-from-the-epoch  and http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213326/how-to-convert-a-string-variable-containing-time-to-time-t-type-in-c This answers your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sscanf_s.
For example:

```
void ScanTime(char* strTime)
{
    int hours;
    int minutes;
    int seconds;

    sscanf_s(strTime, "%d:%d:%d", &hours, &minutes, &seconds);

    printf("hours: %d\nminutes:%d\nseconds:%d\n", hours, minutes, seconds);
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    ScanTime("13:57:44");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's correct, but the real question was how to get the total seconds...

Comment: That's easy:
`int totalSeconds = seconds + minutes*60 + hours*3600;`

Answer (score 0):

Use [strtol](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/).
for example::

```
int a=(int)strtol(numeric_string.c_str(),(char **)NULL,10);
```

if your intension isto simply convert HH:MM:SS, you need to write a function
algorithm would be like(assuming 24Hr format):

1. `split` the string using ":"
2. Convert each part using `strtol` to integer.
3. `last part+(60* middle part)+(60*60*firstpart)` will give you the
   actual value

Comment: What does "for eg" mean?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is not a standard C++ function it greatly depends on what framework or library you are using.

This how it's done in Borland C++ Builder:

```
String Time;
Time = "12:34:56";
TDateTime DT;

try{
    DT = StrToTime(Time);
  }catch(...){String M = "Error converting time string: "+Time; Application->MessageBox(M.c_str(),"ERROR",MB_OK );}
```