# Time string in C++ to microseconds since epoch

Tags: c++, timestamp, epoch

I have a time string object in C++, which is the human readable time since epoch since 1970 of the following form, "2014/04/28 09:17:49.114'556". I want to convert the string into a LONGLONG integer that represents micros since epoch. What may be the easiest way to do this?

Comment: You may want to have a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137748/c-converting-a-time-string-to-seconds-from-the-epoch).

Comment: Thanks that makes sense, this time zone is actually IST, or Indian standard time, any way to tackle that?

Comment: The title says milliseconds but the question says "micros" (and the example suggests microseconds). So which is it?