# Converting ISO8601 string to milliseconds since epoch

Tags: c++, c++14

Sample string:

> 2018-10-31T14:45:21.778952-07:00

I would like to convert it to int64_t representing milliseconds (or even microseconds) since epoch.  The timezone can vary.  The code will be executing on a linux box, but I only have access to std and folly (cannot use any arbitrary 3P libraries).

I searched for this and found a few different ways that do not work for me:

1. strptime() and std::get_time() lose the millisecond precision
2. More importantly, neither of those can deal with timezone offsets
3. Some other solutions depend on 3P libraries

Is there some easy way to do this?

Comment: I found following link. I hope it will be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137748/c-converting-a-time-string-to-seconds-from-the-epoch

Comment: @MJK  Sorry, should've mentioned I looked at that as well.  Since std::get_time uses the tm struct, it loses the millisecond precision as well.

Comment: Once you break apart each of the elements you might want to look into how OS’s convert the RTC into a unix epoch. The algorithms are pretty well known, and can usually be copied and pasted.

Comment: An example can be found here, the important part is converting a date to the number of days since 1970, I don’t remember where I originally found this information: https://forum.osdev.org/viewtopic.php?t=13635&p=93464

Comment: I've updated my question to mention timezones as well.  I can't find any solution that can correctly deal with timezone offsets outside of a 3P library like: https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html

Comment: @van aaaaand you forgot about leap seconds.

Comment: @rubenvb in case you’ve forgotten the Unix epoch explicitly does not handle leap seconds.

Comment: There is no system-lvl API that allows you to deal with any timezone. Typically any given system only cares about it's own timezone and GMT. Historical timezone info (when given location switches between summer/winter time/etc) is in constant flux and keeping every server up-to-date with every government's whims is impractical. Howard's library is is best thing (I know of) that tackles this. He is using 3rd-party tz info and your app is expected to be able to periodically download tz updates (and hope that website is still up and running).

Comment: @C.M. Timezone offsets are not nearly as difficult as timezone names.  It's sad to see there is nothing in the standard library that can deal with it.

I am looking into using Howard's library.  However, that it makes a web call gives me pause.  I assume that if the call fails it will just use the locally stored timezone name data?  We won't be dealing with timezone names, so I don't care about those.  However, making a network call might be an issue.

Comment: @Pratik If standard starts demanding arbitrary tz support this will make probably all of systems currently being used non-conforming. Who needs standard like that? ;) I don't know every aspect of this, but apparently lack of trusted and reliable source of tz info is one of barriers. I am pretty sure you can provide pre-downloaded tz info to Howard's lib and ensure it never "calls" for updates, but then your logic isn't guaranteed to work with timestamps from recent past. Tbh, even having up-to-date tz info isn't a 100% guarantee because gov can (theoretically) change tz info retroactively...

Comment: @van It’s a bit more complicaties than that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16539436/unix-time-and-leap-seconds#comment41898480_16539483. Essentially, wegen converting from a (UTC) datetime you’ll need to know when the clock skipped a second in Unix time. Time is a complicated animal, because we use bad metrics.

Comment: This particular problem doesn't require awareness of timezones since the UTC offset is part of the format.  In case you change your mind on the use of [Howard Hinnant's library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/blob/master/include/date/date.h), this problem requires only including a single header, and is only a few lines of code.  This library has also already been voted into the C++20 working draft.  And for the sample input, the result is 1541022321778952µs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the comments above:

> I am looking into using Howard's library. However, that it makes a web call gives me pause. I assume that if the call fails it will just use the locally stored timezone name data? We won't be dealing with timezone names, so I don't care about those. However, making a network call might be an issue.

[Howard's library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) is layered:

1. A [foundational layer](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) that does not need the IANA time zone database and thus never makes networking calls.  This is a single header, header-only library.
2. A [time zone layer](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html) that is aware of the IANA time zone database.  This layer can be configured to make network calls or not (depending on build flags), or even use your OS's time zone database (except on Windows).

Your application does not require the [time zone layer](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html) as it only deals with UTC offsets, and not time zone names or rules.

Here is a function that converts a `std::string` with your sample format into a `std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, std::chrono::microseconds>`.  That type is a big verbose mouthful for a `system_clock::time_point` except guaranteed to have `microseconds` precision.  The [foundational layer](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) has a type alias for this type called `date::sys_time<std::chrono::microseconds>`.

```
#include "date/date.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

auto
to_sys_time(std::string s)
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    istringstream in{move(s)};
    in.exceptions(ios::failbit);
    sys_time<microseconds> tp;
    in >> parse("%FT%T%z", tp);
    return tp;
}
```

- Put the `string` into a `istringstream`.
- Optionally set the `istringstream` to throw an exception if it fails to parse something (you may choose to handle errors differently).
- Declare your `time_point` with the desired precision.
- Parse it with your desired format.
- Return it.

You can exercise this function like so:

```
int
main()
{
    auto tp = to_sys_time("2018-10-31T14:45:21.778952-07:00");
    using date::operator<<;
    std::cout << tp << " UTC\n";
    std::cout << tp.time_since_epoch() << '\n';
}
```

- Call `to_sys_time` with the desired input string.
- Make the streaming operators in `namespace date` available.
- Print out the `time_point` (this is a UTC `time_point`).
- Extract and print out the `duration` of the `time_point`.

The output of this program is:

```
2018-10-31 21:45:21.778952 UTC
1541022321778952µs
```

This program will port to C++20 by removing `#include "date/date.h"`, `using namespace date;` and `using date::operator<<;`.

Comment: Thanks, Howard!  The right answer is that C++14 standard library does not have a way to parse the timezone offset, and so my only option is to either write that logic myself or use a 3P library.  Your library is the best option.