# C++: Converting date-time between timezones keeping precision

Tags: c++, boost, time

Consider the input: `2014-04-14T16:28:07.023` (no time-zone, milliseconds precision)
I parsed it and I have the parts as numbers.

- The input is always considered to be in UTC
- I want to display it as local time
- I want to keep the milliseconds precision when displaying

I have C++98 and boost 1.51.

I inspected `high_resolution_clock` and `system_clock`, but was unable to produce the final plot for the problem yet.

Comment: Does the accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786201/parsing-of-date-time-from-string-boost?rq=1) answer your question?

Comment: No milliseconds there. I also don't see utc-localtime conversion. But still might lead somewhere...

Comment: What do you mean by classic c++?  Do you mean C++99 as in 1999 the year of the standard as apposed to the classic C++11 as in 2011.  For sure nothing related to your question has changes in the last 20 years of c++.  So your not using boost.  I would start by learning how to process text.  You could probably open up the boost code and take a look at what they have done.  Even if your not going to use it.

Comment: I know how to process text, I should not have mentioned parsing. Let's start from the point where I have the parts as numbers. I have problem with choosing a good combination of utilities and methods for the rest.

Comment: @Dan By the way, I did not say I am using boost. I told that I have it. Meaning that I welcome answers which are using boost.

Comment: @Notinlist Why not increment/decrement the obtained hour and take care of carry digits.

Comment: C++ has a C++98 standard from 1998, and a 2003 update known as C++03 to fix some bugs in the standard's text, without adding features. (C does have a C99 standard from 1999.)

Comment: @user877329 I would have problems at the end of February. I don't want to go on the road where I have to do date handling logic myself.

Comment: How about dropping the milliseconds (save it in a separate variable), do the conversion, then add the milliseconds back? Your question seems as if you have a working answer already, except for the milliseconds part, but milliseconds don't affect the rest of the result.

Comment: @hvd Yes. I wanted to simply say that I don't use C++11, but the one before that. It could be understood from "Classic C++ (not C++11)", but then it was not enough, so I started to refine it and made a mistake: wrote 99 instead of 98. Much ado about nothing.

Comment: @hvd Good idea. Handling milliseconds separately would mean that I can "avoid" boost entirely in regards of this feature because I could use `gmtime` and `localtime`. But on the other hand I already have boost in my project. I also posted an answer. I'm not yet confident about which way I will choose.

Comment: @hvd Your idea made me think harder. With the utility I'm writing I will not do any kind of timezone conversion nor enforcing of any particular variant of date-time facility. I will leave the parts as numbers and expose it to the higher levels like that. On that higher level I will use your method or mine (c_local_adjustor) but that does not matter for now. I would like to value your idea, please post an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested in the comments to post as an answer, here is how it can be done without Boost:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
  int year, month, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond;
  if (std::cin >> year >> month >> day >> hour >> minute >> second >> millisecond) {
    struct tm utc;
    utc.tm_year = year;
    utc.tm_mon = month;
    utc.tm_mday = day;
    utc.tm_hour = hour;
    utc.tm_min = minute;
    utc.tm_sec = second;
    utc.tm_isdst = 0;

    time_t time = timegm(&utc);
    if (time == (time_t) -1)
      abort();

    struct tm *local = localtime(&time);
    if (localtime == NULL)
      abort();

    year = local->tm_year;
    month = local->tm_mon;
    day = local->tm_mday;
    hour = local->tm_hour;
    minute = local->tm_min;
    second = local->tm_sec;

    std::cout << year << ' ' << month << ' ' << day << ' ' << hour << ' ' << minute << ' ' << second << ' ' << millisecond << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Note that the `millisecond` variable is read from input, and written to output, without any modification.

This uses the non-standard `timegm` function, but the documentation for that function contains a more portable implementation that you could include, if you want.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution which will be sufficient for me, but I don't know if it is the best approach in general or not. I'm about to use [`boost::posix_time::ptime`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html) and `boost::date_time`'s [`c_local_adjustor`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/date_time/examples.html#date_time.examples.local_utc_conversion):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/c_local_time_adjustor.hpp>

int main()
{
  typedef boost::posix_time::ptime TP;
  typedef boost::date_time::c_local_adjustor<TP> local_adj;

  TP tUTC(boost::gregorian::date(2014,4,13),boost::posix_time::millisec(23));
  TP tLocal(local_adj::utc_to_local(tUTC));

  std::cout << boost::posix_time::to_simple_string(tUTC) << std::endl;
  std::cout << boost::posix_time::to_simple_string(tLocal) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Will print:

```
2014-Apr-13 00:00:00.023000
2014-Apr-13 02:00:00.023000
```

I did'nt use `using namespace` to show where is what. The `ptime` class has accessors to every detail I need. The `c_local_adjustor` does not have `local_to_utc` method, but it can be worked around.

(I got nowhere with `chrono`, I was able to do only circles in the documentation.)

Comment: +1 This is what I wanted to write up when my system went down. Chrono is "useless" because it is (deliberately) calendar-agnostic.