# Locale does not recognized for custom facet parsing Date / Time

Tags: c++, datetime, boost, locale, boost-date-time

I was looking for a sample to convert date to seconds from an arbitrary epoch (dates minor than the standard 1970)

And I found the following very good sample (from an answer to):
[How to parse date/time from string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786201/how-to-parse-date-time-from-string)

```
#define BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <locale>
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>

namespace bt = boost::posix_time;
const std::locale formats[] = {
std::locale(std::locale::classic(),new bt::time_input_facet("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")),
std::locale(std::locale::classic(),new bt::time_input_facet("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")),
std::locale(std::locale::classic(),new bt::time_input_facet("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")),
std::locale(std::locale::classic(),new bt::time_input_facet("%Y-%m-%d"))};
const size_t formats_n = sizeof(formats)/sizeof(formats[0]);

std::time_t pt_to_time_t(const bt::ptime& pt)
{
    bt::ptime timet_start(boost::gregorian::date(1970,1,1));
    bt::time_duration diff = pt - timet_start;
    return diff.ticks()/bt::time_duration::rep_type::ticks_per_second;

}
void seconds_from_epoch(const std::string& s)
{
    bt::ptime pt;
    for(size_t i=0; i<formats_n; ++i)
    {
        std::istringstream is(s);
        is.imbue(formats[i]);
        is >> pt;
        if(pt != bt::ptime()) break;
    }
    std::cout << " ptime is " << pt << '\n';
    std::cout << " seconds from epoch are " << pt_to_time_t(pt) << '\n';
}
int main()
{
    seconds_from_epoch("2004-03-21 12:45:33");
    seconds_from_epoch("2004/03/21 12:45:33");
    seconds_from_epoch("23.09.2004 04:12:21");
    seconds_from_epoch("2003-02-11");
}
```

Problem is, apparently doesn't work in VC++ 2013 / Boost 1.59, the dates all print as "not a date" (the condition in the loop from "if(pt != bt::ptime())" is never true).

Digging a bit in the debugger for "is >> pt", seems that the MSVC STL looks for the locale in a global table and does not find it.

Is the code missing something?

UPDATE: This seems to be MSVC specific, in Linux Open SUSE 13.2 with GCC 4.9 and Boost 1.59, program works damn fine.